# Side scrolling android game developemnt

Tags: android, side-scroller

I am implementing a side scrolling android game. The player should move in a diagonal direction and the objects around him seem to move back ward.

I have structured my app like the open source project (replica island) by Chris Pruett.

I can render the obstacles and the player, but unable to move the obstacles.

Any help in this direction is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

First of all: I am not familiar with the source code of "Replica Island" (I've played the game, though).

If you want to move/physically manipulate objects in your world, I'd suggest you use a 2D physics engine. A good start would be [jBox2D](http://www.jbox2d.org/) or [chipmunk for Java](http://code.google.com/p/chipmunk-java/). Both are very similar.

It is quite easy to integrate in a game and fun to use, but the approach of character controlling is quite different to a game without a physics engine. For example, you apply forces to your character to move him around and do not set his speed/position manually.

I'm sure you'll find plenty of examples and tutorials for both physics engines out there.

HTH